# Is $\mathbb{Z}$/(10) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$/(2) $\times$ $ \ \mathbb{Z}$/(5)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

a) Is $\mathbb{Z}$/(10) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$/(2) $\times$  $ \ \mathbb{Z}$/(5)?

b) Is $\mathbb{Z}$/(8) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$/(2) $\times$  $ \ \mathbb{Z}$/(4)?

I'm not sure how I would do these questions?

Comment: What are you viewing these structures as? Rings, or groups? Regardless, the usual way would be to try writing down an isomorphism, or exhibit some property that holds for one structure but not the other, i.e. having elements of a certain order.

Comment: isomorphisms as rings

Comment: Think about what happens when you try to 'combine' rings created by ideals $(x),(y)$, $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $x,y$ are *not* relatively prime.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem for the first. In the second, look at orders of elements.

Comment: Pedro, could you explain how I would use the chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: T.bongers, for b), I noticed that the first ring has an element of order 8 with respect to addition, while the second doesn't. Why does this imply that the rings are not isomorphic? From the properties of an isomorphism, how do you show a contradiction assuming that there is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 3):

For the first one you can consider the ring homomorphism
$$\varphi:\Bbb Z_{10}\to\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_5\\
k\mapsto(k\%2,k\%5)$$
and show that it is an isomorphism. Remember: Both sides have $10$ elements, so it suffices to either show injectivity or surjectivity to get the bijectivity.

The second case is not even true for groups. Can you find an element in $(\Bbb Z_8,+)$ of an order $n$ such that no element in the left side has order $n$ ?

Comment: when checking the order, do I use addition or multiplication?

Comment: Also, how does the multiplication and addition operation look like for the second ring with the cartesian product?

Comment: Addititve order. And multiplication and addition are defined pointwise $(k,l)+(k',l')=(k+k',l+l')$ and $(k,l)*(k',l')=(k*k',l*l')$

Comment: the element 3 has order 8. None of the elements in the second ring have order 8. From the properties of isomorphisms, how can I derive a contradiction, assuming that there is an isomorphism? I know isomorphisms preserve order, but why does it preserve order?

Comment: @josh: Do you know the relation of the order of $a\in G$ and the order of $φ(a)$ if $φ:G\to H$ is a homomorphism ?

Comment: aren't they suppose to be equal?  I'm not sure why that is. Can you prove it?

Comment: I actually just proved it in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588565/question-about-homomorphism-of-cyclic-group/588573#588573). So this tells you that the order of the image divides the order of $a$. Now what does that mean for the inverse $φ^{-1}$ which is also a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

A group homomorphism from $\mathbb Z/(10)$ to a group is determined by the image of $1$. Since $\mathbb Z/(2)\times\mathbb Z/(5)$ has ten elements there are at most 10 homomorphisms to this group. If you cannot think of anything better, check all of them.